# Transform a list of list (containing matrices) into a data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

I have a list of list which I want to transform into a data.frame.
Some of the element in the "inner" list contains a matrix and I want to preserve columns and their name.

I made quite some progress using `lapply`, and now I ended up with another list which has this pattern:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$X
[1] 0.100

[[1]]$Y
                   VAL   LCI  UCI  
AB                 1000  500  1300 
CD                 30    10   400
```

This pattern repeat for like 200 rows.

Now the question is that I want to create a data.frame with 4 columns: X, VAL, LCI, UCI. Obviously I would have rows which alternate "AB" and "CD" since these rownames are fixed in my list.

Anyone has an idea on how to perform this?
Here is a reproducible example - although not fancy, `list1` produced by this code is **exactly** the object that I need to transform in a dataframe:

```
#Create list x
var1 <- 0.100 
var1 <- list(var1)
names(var1) <- "x"

#Create list y
var2 <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)
rownames(var2) <- c("AB","CD")
colnames(var2) <- c("VAL","LCI","UCI")
var2 <- list(var2)
names(var2) <- "y"

#Create a second element
var3 <- 0.200
var3 <- list(var3)
names(var3) <- "x"

var4 <- matrix(7:12, nrow = 2)
rownames(var4) <- c("AB","CD")
colnames(var4) <- c("VAL","LCI","UCI")
var4 <- list(var4)
names(var4) <- "y"

#Create a list
list1 <- list(c(var1,var2),c(var3,var4))
```

Comment: share a reproducible example.

Comment: @M-- I have added a reprex which - although not fancy - create an object (list1) which is exactly what I need to transform in a dataframe with 4 column (X, VAL, LCI, UCI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your request but I give it a try! So, based on your example, please find below a reprex

**Reprex**

- Code of the function `DFbindRows`

```r
DFbindRows <- function(x){
  x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, as.data.frame))
  names(x) <- gsub("y.","",names(x))
  return(x)
}
```

- Test of the function on your data `list1`

```r
DF <- DFbindRows(list1)
#>       x   VAL   LCI   UCI
#> AB  0.1     1     3     5
#> CD  0.1     2     4     6
#> AB1 0.2     7     9    11
#> CD1 0.2     8    10    12
```

*NB: the number after AB or CD is mandatory because it is not allowed to have duplicated row names in a `dataframe`*

- Check of the object class

```r
class(DF)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Workaround for the `row names` problem**

To circumvent the problem I pointed out in the *Nota Bene* above, it is possible

- to create an ID column in which the rows `AB` and `CD` alternate, and
- to set numbers as `row.names`.

So, please find below the function `DFbindRows2` which offers you the possibility to get such a `dataframe`

**Reprex**

- Code of the function `DFbindRows2`

```r
DFbindRows2 <- function(x){
  x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, as.data.frame))
  x$ID <- rep(c("AB", "CD"), nrow(x)/2)
  x <- x[,c("ID", 
            names(x)[-grep("ID",names(x))])]
  row.names(x) <- seq(nrow(x))
  names(x) <- gsub("y.","",names(x))
  return(x)
}
```

- Test of the function on your data list1

```r
DF <- DFbindRows2(list1)
#>   ID   x   VAL   LCI   UCI
#> 1 AB 0.1     1     3     5
#> 2 CD 0.1     2     4     6
#> 3 AB 0.2     7     9    11
#> 4 CD 0.2     8    10    12
```

- Check of the object class

```r
class(DF)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think you can remove the `x <-` and `return(x)` and it will still return the object when you assign it to `DF`

Comment: Hello @Mike, thank you so much for your advice. I just edited my answer. Cheers

Comment: @userq8957289475, NB: I updated my answer so that the name of columns is as expected. In doing this edit, Mike's comment no longer applies. If this answer is what you were looking for, please mark it as accepted. If not, please tell me what is wrong. Cheers.